# JQGrid within a dialog

Tags: jqgrid

How will you display a JQGrid within a dialog?

Answer (score 5):

in html page place table tag which will be used to construct grid inside dialog div like

```
<div id="dialog-div">
 <table id="JqGrid">
</table>
 <div id="pager" style="text-align: center;  </div>
</div>
```

then in js first set dialog settings like

```
$("#dialog-div").dialog({
            width: 'auto',
            resizable: false,
            height: '395',
            autoOpen: false,
            open: function (event, ui) {
           ConstructJqGrid();
            },

        });
function ConstructJqGrid(){


jQuery("#JqGrid").jqGrid({
...
   colModel: [ 
      ... 
      {name:'price', ..., editable:true, edittype:'custom', editoptions:{custom_element: myelem, custom_value:myvalue} },
      ...
   ]
...
})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it, with AJAX to get the page containing my jqGrid :

```
$.ajax({
   [...],
   success: function( data ){
      var popup = document.createElement( "div" );

      // Appending
      $( popup ).append( data );
      $( "body" ).append( popup );

      // Dialoging
      $( popup ).dialog({
         [...]
      });
   }
});
```

PS : I don't know the rules about necroposting but since the answer was never given, I chose to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jquery-ui dialog use [this page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/),the first example will show you how to create a dialog with #dialog. Then [this page](http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) will have a have a basic JQGrid example which you will embed into your #dialog. If you are using a different type of a dialog, the process should be similar.

Comment: Hi vladikoff! Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the jQgrid demo app is quiet complex for a newbie like me. Also, the samples are displayed in a tab not in individual dialogs which is what i want to learn.